# Connecting Exchange Online with Powershell without basic authentication

Tags: azure, powershell, office365, exchange-server

I still don't get the point, how to connect to Exchange Online without Basic Authentication.
Fact is, that basic authentication is EOL: 
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Exchange-Team-Blog/Improving-Security-Together/ba-p/805892

With Exchange Online Powershell Module V2 (https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Exchange-Team-Blog/Improving-Security-Together/ba-p/805892) I'm able to connect

```
    $Credential=Get-Credential
    Connect-ExchangeOnline –Credential $Credential
```

The Code above works.
But only the get-EXO... Commands are available.
What do I have to do, to have the command `Get-OrganizationConfig` available?

At the End I need to have admin commands to do ExchangeOnline administration without any user intervention. Username/password has to be provided as parameter.

Answer (score 2):

If WinRM Basic Auth disabled on the client machine, you can access 9 EXO* cmdlets, but you can't access remaining 700+ cmdlets.

To access all the cmdlets, you need to enable WinRM basic in the client machine. However, it uses modern auth for authentication, it requires basic auth header to transport OAuth tokens.

Comment: I've seen that office 365 report as well. So I was wondering if there is really no other way. Now I just saw that there is an update on that: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-auth-and-exchange-online-february-2020-update/ba-p/1191282   It seems, that microsoft disables the basic auth option in october this year. But they are not yet fully ready with the EXO module by now.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Powershell code issue, which is what we are here to help with. So, this really should be moved to SuperUser or StackExchange, but since you are here. know that this 'connect to O365/Azure without Basic auth' is nothing new. You've been able to do this for a very long time now.

Point of note, Azure initially and ADAL/Modern off by default, it is now on by default, but for now, if you are doing stuff that does not use ADAL/MA, it will fall back to basic, that of course now is not a thing with the EOL of Basic Auth (that folks re now panicking about - honestly for little reason).

***Due to the overall industry-wide position in the risk management/security space, everyone should be connecting use MFA anyway*** and of course MFA cannot be used with Basic Auth.

It's been well documented for a very long time. Just search for it using say...

> ['PowerShell connect to exchange online adal'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%27powershell%20connect%20to%20exchange%20online%20adal%27&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=%27powershell%20connect%20to%20exchange%20online%20adal%27&sc=0-44&sk=&cvid=D43596A9E7E44FC5ADDBEFC569A22693)
>
> ['PowerShell connect to exchange online modern auth'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%27PowerShell%20connect%20to%20exchange%20online%20modern%20auth%27&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=%27powershell%20connect%20to%20exchange%20online%20modern%20auth%27&sc=0-51&sk=&cvid=DD4850E5859842148C0BAC1CDFD740E0)
>
> ['PowerShell connect to exchange online MFA'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%27PowerShell%20connect%20to%20exchange%20online%20MFA%27&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=%27powershell%20connect%20to%20exchange%20online%20mfa%27&sc=3-43&sk=&cvid=1C58CDDC34F748CA8F3BEC82BC683565)
>
> ['PowerShell connect to exchange online 2 factor auth'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%27PowerShell%20connect%20to%20exchange%20online%202%20factor%20auth%27&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=%27powershell%20connect%20to%20exchange%20online%202%20factor%20auth%27&sc=0-53&sk=&cvid=A5CBBD119A5C4418957338E8FFDAB692)

... and you will get all the MS docs as well as all other blog posts on the topic.

> [Connect to Exchange Online PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps)
>
> If you want to use multi-factor authentication (MFA) to connect to
>   Exchange Online PowerShell, you need to download and use the Exchange
>   Online Remote PowerShell Module. For more information, see Connect to
>   Exchange Online PowerShell using multi-factor authentication.
>
> [Connect to Exchange Online PowerShell using multi-factor
>   authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell/mfa-connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps)
>
> [PowerShell Basics: Connecting to Exchange Online Using Multi-Factor
>   Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/canitpro/powershell-basics-connecting-to-exchange-online-using-multi-factor-authentication)
>
> [Connecting to Office 365 using PowerShell and Modern
>   Authentication](https://www.quadrotech-it.com/blog/connecting-to-office-365-using-powershell-and-modern-authentication)
>
> [Connect to Exchange Online with Powershell, Modern Authentication and
>   Conditional Access](https://www.imab.dk/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell-modern-authentication-and-conditional-access)
>
> [Connect to Exchange Online PowerShell without Basic Authentication
>   (Step by Step)](https://o365reports.com/2019/12/11/connect-exchange-online-powershell-without-basic-authentication/)

```
# Install Exchange Online PowerShell V2 Module: 
Install-Module PowerShellGet -Force
Install-Module –Name ExchangeOnlineManagement

# Connect to Exchange Online PowerShell With Modern Authentication: 
Connect-ExchangeOnline

# Additional Usecases for Connect-ExchangeOnline: 
PowerShell
$Credential=Get-Credential
Connect-ExchangeOnline –Credential $Credential
Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName <UPN>
```

Answer (score 0):

the Exo v2-Module includes all "old" cmdlets. Mine does, and MS also says, it does

> The new cmdlets in the EXO V2 module are meant to replace their
>   older, less efficient equivalents. However, the original cmdlets are
>   still available in the EXO V2 module for backwards compatibility after
>   you create a session to connect to your Exchange Online
>   organization.

see [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online/exchange-online-powershell-v2/exchange-online-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps)

Anyhow, the situation is quite unsatisfying, as you can't use EXOv2 in Scheduled Scripts. There's a newer Verison of the Blogpost from MSExchangeTeam [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-auth-and-exchange-online-february-2020-update/ba-p/1191282). It also has Information about RPS:

> PowerShell, scripts and automation – we are absolutely committed to
>   supporting non-interactive scripts via Remote PowerShell using
>   Certificate Based Authentication. We’re still working hard on the
>   code, have some customers working on this with us already, and will
>   have more to say on this in the next couple of months.

I assume they'll delay disabling of Basic Auth for some time, because they can't offer a solution in-time.

Regards

Filipp